# Java method in main method executed one after another or does not wait for another?

Tags: java

I have 4 method in java .

```
m1(),m2(),m3(),m4()
```

in same sequence as above .

Now `m1` take 7hour `m2` take 2hr .

So my question is does `m2` will executed after `7hour` and wait to complete the `m1` or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling all the methods in sequence from a single thread, then these methods will be executed in sequence i.e. m2() will run after 7 hours.

Comment: Thanks sir.  I am calling all method from java main standalone method then what is the sequence?

Comment: The method will be completed in the sequence, you are calling, as methods you are calling in synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Method one will have to finish each line of code from top to bottom. If it can finish successfully without crashing then M2 will execute after M1 is finished entirely. The only way they can execute at the same time is with Multithreading.

Threads can be created by:

1. Extending the Thread class
2. Implementing the Runnable Interface

Comment: Thanks sir. I am calling all method from java main standalone method then what is the sequence?

Comment: They will just be on one thread (the main thread) and m2 will execute only when m1 is fully completed.